# Need Help Converting Laptop Display To An external HDMI Monitor

Tags: laptop, display, external

I have an "Samsung LTN140AT01-G03" Diplay which i removed from "acer 4740g" laptop.

I was planning to convert that display into an external Monitor, But im not able to  find a compatible controller board for this panel as its not available in India, and many market places does not ship to India (ebay as well).

Anyway, I have found an universal controller board In local market "Model=vs t56u11.2":

[image]

this controller board is advertised as an controller board for TV's panel, i couldn't find any blogs or videos using this controller board for an laptop lcd

-therefore i wanted to know , Can i use this controller board for my display panel?

-and , if yes,

my display panel does not have an separate backlight cable(im assuming it doesn't require a separate cable)
so,if there is no backlight cable , how can i connect the display to the controller board

this display just has an 40pin Lvds Single channel port LVDS 40PIN:

[image]

-thus how do i connect the display to this controller board?

-and the female jack which goes into the motherboard in smaller in size , so i guess it wont connect to this male port on the controlle board , so will i need to buy an new lvds 40 pin cable which matches with the board?
[image of the lvds port on the board (black port)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmK9G.jpg)

thus , can you guys help me out on those problems

thanks

note:- i have removed the lvds cable from the laptop as well , one end has an lvds 40pin and other end two female jack(one is an small 40pin and other one is an small 6pin , im assuming the small 6 pin one connects to laptops 720p webcam )
[The oem cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgJYC.jpg)

Comment: I found this https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/For-LTN140AT01-G03-40-Pin-1366-768-LVDS-LED-panel-TV-analog-driver-board-DIY-kit/173885440456?hash=item287c6141c8:g:bDcAAOSwAsRfGu9n&var=472609389099

Comment: and then you can use it as a monitor - problem is that a secondhand 22 inch monitor with stand second hand is 40GBP ....

Comment: thanks for your reply @JohnnyVegas

actually i have seen this on ebay and on many diffrent online market places but none of those deliver to my country and as for ebay , ebay is not available over here in my country      

therefore i only have access to the "vs t56u11.2" board which is apparently a universal board and its pretty cheap , it has an "lvds" port as well as an "inverter" port.

here is the link to the details of this board https://www.kazmielecom.com/2018/09/23/vs-t56u11-2-software-free-download-all-resolution.html

soo, can i use this board ?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas  i had a question about backlight connection, 

as this panel doesnt not have an seperate cable for backlight power
how does this the panel get the power for backlight?

does it get power through 40 pin lvds port itself?
or the 40 pin lvds cable gets seperated into two diffrent(backlight , lvds)

let me knows
thanks

Comment: The screen will light up without needing a separate connection

Comment: @JohnnyVegas i will try getting the "vs t56u11." board , so as you said ,
i will need to just connect the lvds port with the panel just using the lvds cable right? the display will light up and work properly just with a connection with lvds port?

the board has an backlight inverter port as well , so the display will light up even without using those port?

thanks

Comment: I have no idea but you will need to try the board out yourself. Modern lcd panels do not have a separate backlight input - it tends to be included in the main cable.